# Why RandomData.ALG_TRNG does not exist in javacard development kit 3.0.5?

Tags: security, javacard

I am trying to use ALG_TRNG for random number generation in my applet, but I don't know why neither IntelliJ nor Eclipse do not autocomplete `javacard.security.RandomData.OneShot` or `javacard.security.RandomData.ALG_TRNG`.
I have downloaded JCDK from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-archive-downloads-javame-downloads.html#license-lightbox).
I think these two have added to JCDK from the 3.0.5 version, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It should work since ALG_TRNG is supported since 3.0.5.
try creating an object of RandomData and see if u get any error.

*RandomData o_Rand = RandomData.getInstance(RandomData.ALG_TRNG);*